# don't cache some HTML

Tags: php, mediawiki

I would like to know if I can exclude some of the HTML from being cached. I am using MediaWiki software. So any MediaWiki solution or any other PHP solution will work as well.

My Mediawiki pages are cached and I am implementing the site notice feature which expires after few days. But when pages are cached, it doesn't honor my expiration date and being displayed all the time. so I want to exclude that part of the code from being cached. I am implementing it as a MediaWiki extension.

Thanks

Comment: browsers cache whole pages, not parts

Comment: Browsers cache whole resources, not whole pages.  HTML is separate from the rest of the resources on the page.  If you have some JavaScript to display a notice on your page where caching is disallowed, you can still have the HTML for the page cached and have the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki caching works in many layers. There are a number of [server side caches](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCache), apart from the caching in the client. (As you might have noticed, MW i notoriously slow, unless you implement at least some of the caching functionalities.)

First of all you will want to figure out which sitenotices are cached. As I'm sure you are aware, there is [more than one place](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/Sitenotice) where you can set the sitenotice:

- `MediaWiki:Anonnotice`
- `MediaWiki:Sitenotice`
- `$wgSiteNotice` in `LocalSettings.php`
- Through a few different extensions

Do they all stay on the page for too long? 
Secondly, you can try and figure out where your sitenotice is cached:

- Is there any difference if you are logged in/out? Some parts of the interface can be harder cached for anonymous users.
- Does the message disappear if you clear you browsers cache?
- Try and disable [Varnish](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aVarnish_caching) (or Squid), if you are using any of them.
- Temporarily disable [$wgEnableParserCache](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgEnableParserCache) to see what difference it makes.
- Set `$wgCachePages = false;` in your LocalSettings.php, to try and disallow client side caching

Comment: I am not using any built-in site notice feature. I am using pNotify on my site to display maintenance notices. sysop can setup a notice to display for certain amount of time. During that time, I either don't want browser to cache that file OR better just not that part of the JS and HTML code.
Clearing my browser cache doesn't help since the content is loaded from cached html pages by MediaWiki.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want do use the built in features, that already takes care of all the cashing logic for you?

Comment: Yes, We are displaying something else in the site notice area permanently. So we can't use the site notice feature. In addition, we wanted the site notice to be administered by non-technical sysop user from the Admin Dashboard I created for them. The site notice should automatically start displaying on specified date/time and should also stop displaying on specified date/time. Also Site notice should not display for specified amount of days once dismissed. I can't do that using built-in site notice feature.